# How to make heterostructure/heterojunction structure?

Tags: density-functional-theory, software, electronic-structure, wien2k

How can I make a heterostructure or a heterojunction of ZnO/MgZnO for optimization with WIEN2k code?

Comment: What type of calculations do you want to do? If you make the heterostructure, it won't be periodic by it self, and the software will understand as a single material. Other way to study the heterostructure is working with each system separately ant then use the idea of band off-set [1] to model the heterostructure.

[1] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Band_offset

Answer (score 4):

You can start from the experimental CIFs for each structure ZnO and MgZnO.

Then, using a software that allows you to manipulate the structures, you can generate a supercell, make cuts and convert the symmetry crystal to a molecular system. You will end with two data files, one for each system.

Using the same software you can create a new system using both the data files from the previous step.

I know, for sure, that [Material Studio](https://www.3dsbiovia.com/products/collaborative-science/biovia-materials-studio/) and [QuantumATK](https://www.synopsys.com/silicon/quantumatk.html) can do this task (but they are too expensive to buy just for that). [Atomsk](https://atomsk.univ-lille.fr/index.php), [CIF2Cell](https://sourceforge.net/projects/cif2cell/), and [Nanocut](https://bitbucket.org/aradi/nanocut/src/master/) can help to generate the final data files with the supercells.

A note: if using the final structure for DFT calculation, it will not work as a heterostrucure/heterojuntion. It will be seeing  by WEIN2k (or any other code) as a single structure. To study as a heterostrucure/heterojuntion you can determine the electronic properties of each system, and them, using the band off set theory, simulate the band structure for the heterostrucure/heterojuntion.